# LINQ Concat child lists in a list

Tags: c#, linq

In my code I have a List of ObjectA each of which has a list of ObjectB. I would like to get one list of all the ObjectBs in my list of ObjectAs.

If I have this objects:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<ObjectB> Children {get; set;}
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public string ChildName {get; set;}
}
```

And this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var myList = 
        new List<ObjectA>{
            new ObjectA{
                Name = "ItemA 1", 
                Children = new List<ObjectB>{
                        new ObjectB{ChildName = "ItemB 1"},
                        new ObjectB{ChildName = "ItemB 2"}
                    }
            },
            new ObjectA{
                Name = "ItemA 2", 
                Children = new List<ObjectB>{
                        new ObjectB{ChildName = "ItemB 3"},
                        new ObjectB{ChildName = "ItemB 4"}
                    }
            }
        };
    // What code would I put here to concat all the ObjectBs?
}
```

I want to get a `List<ObjectB>` with 4 `ObjectB` items:

> ItemB 1
>   ItemB 2
>   ItemB 3
>   ItemB 4

Comment: Currently there are "only" 4,245 duplicates (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinq%5Dselectmany) and still asking this trivial question.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't call to mind the right terminology. Did several queries, but no results says `SelectMany`.

Comment: @MKenyonII Searching for [the exact wording you used for your title](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=LINQ+Concat+child+lists+in+a+list) results in a page *full* of questions with this answer.

Comment: True, sometimes typing it out in a question helps formulate the thoughts. Shall I delete this question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var allObjectB = myList.SelectMany(x=>x.Children).ToList();
```

Answer (score 13):

You can just use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = mylist.SelectMany(a => a.Children).ToList();
```

SelectMany allows you to pass in a function that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, and it itself then returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (unlike Select, which would return `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`.
The result contains all of those enumerables concatenated together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would have done it (before I saw the SelectMany answers...)

http://ideone.com/piypJq

```
// Create variable to store all ObjectB objects.
var allObjB = new List<ObjectB>();

// Add all children from each ObjectA.
myList.ForEach(x => allObjB.AddRange(x.Children));

// and confirm that they are all in allObjB
allObjB.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ChildName));
```